# What is the difference between json.dumps and str()?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the difference between `json.dumps(..)` and `str(..)`?

Don't they both convert json to string?

Comment: No. `str()` converts to a **Python** string, `json.dumps()` produces a string that conforms to the JSON standard. The two are orthogonal.

Comment: And although Javascript syntax (of which JSON is a subset) and Python syntax are close in many respects, they are far from the same. Don't confuse the two.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. In fact in (I believe most) implementations of Python, `str(object)` wraps strings in single quotes, which is *not* valid JSON.

An example:

```
In [17]: print str({"a": 1})
{'a': 1}
```

`str(boolean)` is also not valid JSON:

```
In [18]: print str(True)
True
```

`__str__`, can, however, be overridden in user defined classes to ensure that objects return JSON representations of themselves.